# Erasing a thread inside the function it makes

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, vector

I am working on a server that has a vector of threads like this:

```
vector<thread> thred;
```

And each time a client connects to the server, it creates a new thread in the server,like this:

```
thred.push_back(thread(NewClient, ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen));
thred[thred.size()-1].detach();
```

Where NewClient is a function with arguments ClientSocket, recvbuf, and recvbuflen. So my question is if there is any way or function I can use inside NewClient to close the thread and erase the element of the vector that the fuction itself is using.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: One problem I can think of, in order to synchronize this so that you don't get any data races you would need some kind of mutex lock, but if you erase the locking thread while it still has the resource locked, you have no more thread to unlock the resource with. Which would permanently lock your program.

Comment: @simpel01 right now that is what the program does, the vector grows for each connection, and my objective is to have just an element for each connection that there is in the moment, so when NewClient ends I would like to erase the thread and element of the vector? is there any way?

Comment: @Stephen yes, that is a future problem, but currently we dont have mutex, so iam wondering if there is something to close the thread, erase the vector, and unlock the mutex(inside the function NewClient, i

Comment: The only solution I can think of, instead of using thread, create a vector of futures that only have a return value when the thread is ready to close. Then in the main thread where the vector is defined, you would have some code that periodically checks the vector to see if any of the futures have returned, their threads would already have closed and so it would be a matter of simply erasing that element of the vector.

Comment: After detaching thread, original thread variable does not retain any information about thread. So you can remove element from vector right away (or not ad it in the first place)

Comment: What's the point of having your thread ids in vector if you are detaching them anyways?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot that was more or less what I was looking for. The mutex created in the NewClient would be closed too? And how could I do it inside the function?

Comment: @SergeyA I am really new in threads, I just read that was an efficient way for multithreading servers

Comment: @19mike95, there is nothing efficient about it. I think, before writing any code, you need to understand multithreading better.

Comment: @19mike95 why do you need vector of threads in the first place? Why are you detaching them?

Comment: Ask yourself "What am I doing with this `vector` of `thread`s?" If the answer is nothing, discard it. Typoically one holds onto these threads to `join` on them later to prevent something from happening (like the program exiting) until all of the threads have finished, but these `thread`s have been detached. If you are holding on to the `thread`s to get the thread ID to kill them later, I'd caution against that. Killing a running thread can get ugly.

Comment: @user4581301 after detaching thread, original thread object loses its id. You cannot use it even for that.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot useful to know. I'd never tried it. That removes dangerous meddling from the list of things one can do with the thread, reducing the options down to not much.

Comment: if a client has a thread, then make the client own the thread...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a `map<int,thread>` instead of a `vector` to store your threads, and pass the thread's map key as an additional parameter to the thread method.  When the thread is done executing, it can remove itself from the master table.

The map key can be something simple like an ever-incrementing integer value.

Don't forget to wrap the table with a mutex or something similar, as Stephan has said.

Comment: I see what you say about the map with the key parameter(to know which thread to erase no?), but I dont get how could I close the mutex.

Comment: Yes, the map key is passed to the thread so the thread can erase its own entry in the map (`map.remove`).  "Wrap the table with a mutex" means to `lock()` the mutex before accessing it, then `unlock()` after.  Declare the mutex at the same scope as the thread array (not within the thread itself). Check out http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create another vector

```
vector<int> thread_exit_time;
```

and set it to the sytem time when the thread function `NewClient` exits. Instead of calling `thred.push_back` you can check the `thread_exit_time` and replace those dead threads.

Since you call `detach` there is no other way to check whether the thread is alive of not.

It maybe better to creat a vector of `pair`

```
vector<std::pair<thread,int>> thread;
```

to make sure both vectors are synced.

Anyway, you should first think about why you need to keep a list of *detached* threads as @SergeyA mentioned.